# To keep OS commands output in one line

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script to format the output of .csv file, where I am using pssh to run command on 1000+ servers (saved in /tmp/hosts), I am able to manage command outputs in one line by inserting comma "," but can't keep all in one line 
Note: Below Server names is just an example, In real, server names are different and OS commands is based on user's input.

I tried appending "," between commands with - 'echo "$(uname -a), $(date)"'.
But unable to keep in one line, as what I am expecting below.

I am using the below command

```
pssh -h /tmp/hosts -x '-q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes' -i 'echo "$(uname -a), $(date)"'

[1] 09:17:00 [FAILURE] SERVER1 Exited with error code 255 
[2] 09:17:00 [SUCCESS] SERVER2 
Linux SERVER2 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Sat Jan 26 09:34:22 CET 2019 
[3] 09:17:00 [SUCCESS] SERVER3 
Linux SERVER3 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Sat Jan 26 09:34:22 CET 2019 
[4] 09:17:00 [SUCCESS] SERVER4 
Linux SERVER4 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Sat Jan 26 09:34:22 CET 2019 
[5] 09:17:00 [SUCCESS] SERVER5 
Linux SERVER5 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Sat Jan 26 09:34:22 CET 2019 
[6] 09:19:52 [FAILURE] HOST1 Exited with error code 255 
[7] 09:19:52 [FAILURE] HOST2 Exited with error code 255 
[8] 09:19:52 [FAILURE] HOST3 Timed out, Killed by signal 9 
[9] 09:19:52 [FAILURE] HOST4 Timed out, Killed by signal 9
```

I am Expecting the output as below

```
[FAILURE], SERVER1, Exited with error code 255 
[SUCCESS], SERVER2, Linux SERVER2 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Sat Jan 26 09:34:22 CET 2019 
[SUCCESS], SERVER3, Linux SERVER3 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Sat Jan 26 09:34:22 CET 2019 
[SUCCESS], SERVER4, Linux SERVER4 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Sat Jan 26 09:34:22 CET 2019 
[SUCCESS], SERVER5, Linux SERVER5 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, Sat Jan 26 09:34:22 CET 2019 
[FAILURE], HOST1, Exited with error code 255 
[FAILURE], HOST2, Exited with error code 255 
[FAILURE], HOST3, Timed out Killed by signal 9 
[FAILURE], HOST4, Timed out Killed by signal 9
```

Comment: `[2] 09:17:00 [SUCCESS] SERVER2 <br/>` is the `<br/>` really part of the output? You might better use `ansible` for the job.

Comment: No no , <br/> Not a part of code. I was used just format to next line . I have remove that.

Answer (score 0):

The newline is inserted by the `pssh` utility. You can try to use the option `--inline` or `--inline-stdout` with the `pssh` utility. Or use `-o` options to set up the output directory and then use a bash script to properly format the output according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
pssh -i -H Server "hostname| tr '\n' '\t';date"
```

Just pipe the first command into tr and it will display the outputs on one line seperated by a tab

Answer (score -1):

```
grep pattern file | awk '{print}' ORS='" '
```

Comment: Since this is a newbie level question, You might salvage this answer by writing a sentence above the code that explains how the pipe operator in his context performs the join operation requested by the user.